# ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess returns 403 for POST methods

Tags: c#, api, azure-web-app-service

We have several POST & GET APIs exposed via web application. In each of them user access is checked by
ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAcces. For GET methods everything works always fine, but for POST and for **some** installations 403 (Forbidden) is returned during the check. Application is always hosted on Azure App Service, so it seems it's something related to the service setting itself. The customer is not aware of any "special" change made in the settings, but who knows - on the other site and exactly the same installation process no issues at all. Also, version with disabled check works just fine. So, what may be the setting which actually blocks CheckAcces?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for returning a 403 Forbidden error from the  ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess method for POST requests.

1. This is due to incorrect Role Definition, check the roles used in ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess are properly defined, and the user has the correct role assigned.
2. And also due to inadequate permissions for the users, check whether the user has the necessary permissions to access the API. This can be checked in Azure App Service by reviewing the App Service Authentication/Authorization settings.

[image]

[image]

3. Network Security Group Rules, check the Network Security Group (NSG) rules are not blocking the request. Check the NSG rules for the Azure App Service and make sure that the incoming traffic from the source IP is allowed.

Creation of Application Security Group and Network Security Group.

[image]

[image]

4. Custom Authorization Middleware, If a custom authorization middleware is used, it may be interfering with the ClaimsPrincipalPermission.CheckAccess method. Check the custom middleware code to make sure it is not blocking the request.
5. Azure App Service Configuration, check the Azure App Service configuration is not affecting the request. And Check the App Service Configuration settings to make sure that everything is set up correctly.

References taken from:

[Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-in-azure-web-app)

[NSG Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview)

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).